# Getting exceptions while trying to display encoded images with Thymeleaf (Java, Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, thymeleaf, ioutils

So, i have a form that allows user to upload an image, which will be encoded with IOUtils.toByteArray and persisted to a database as a bytea. In a controller method i get this byte array and encode it to string:

```
@GetMapping("/{user_id}")
public String view(@PathVariable("user_id") Long user_id, Model model) {
    User user = userService.getById(user_id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    byte[] profilePictureBytes = user.getProfilePicture();

    if (profilePictureBytes != null) {
        String encodedImage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(profilePictureBytes);
        model.addAttribute("encodedImage", encodedImage);
    }
    return "user-page";
}
```

On a user-page html file i try to decode it like this:

```
<img th:src="*{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ ${encodedImage}}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

but it keeps throwing the same 2 exceptions:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ ${encodedImage}" (template: "user-page" - line 27, col 6

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

While debugging, the "encodedImage" variable prints out a correct string, so the problem must be within my Thymeleaf syntax.

Would be really grateful if someone could give me a hand with this one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the surronding context of your snippet looks like, so the following is just a wild guess and might not solve your problem: at first glance, to me using `*{}` does not seem necessary. `*{}` is used to access fields of the object set in `th:object` in the parent element. Maybe try `${'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+encodedImage}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest expressions like you are doing -- `*{ ... ${ ... } ... }` is not valid Thymeleaf syntax.  See the Thymeleaf documentation on [appending texts](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-texts).  In most cases, literal substitutions I think are most expressive.

```
<img th:src="|data:image/jpeg;base64,${encodedImage}|" alt="Profile Picture">
```

Or if you prefer regular String concatenation.

```
<img th:src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ ${encodedImage}" alt="Profile Picture">

or

<img th:src="${'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ encodedImage}" alt="Profile Picture">
```